# Can't run python script with $python file.py

Tags: python, windows, powershell, visual-studio-code

I just downloaded VSCode and Python today and am attempting to follow a Python tutorial course. But every time I try to run my program in the terminal, it won't open / can't find my file.

This is the code I'm trying to run:

[image: My Beginner Code]

(Edit: The 'Hi' is random and has no bearing on the code I was trying to run)

And this is what happens when I try to run it:

```sh
PS C:\Users\...\Hellow World> $python HW.py
At line:1 char:9
+ $python HW.py
+         ~~~~~
Unexpected token 'HW.py'. in expression or statement
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

[image: Beginner Code Error Output]

I downloaded Python from the Microsoft Store. It's version 3.9.1

Comment: Your code snippet isn't present in the directory you are running your code in . Please try to run your code be pressing Ctrl F5

Comment: `$python` is a variable in Windows PS. You want to invoke `python` (no dollar sign).

Comment: @kishankeswani I'm not sure how you came to that conclusion. The error the OP included is a parse error for PS. `HW.py` didn't have the chance to be interpreted as a filename, let alone checked for existence.

Answer (score 2):

When you write

```
$python HW.py
```

in Windows PowerShell, the token `$python` is expanded as a *[variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-7.1)*. You want to invoke the Python interpreter, which is just `python` (note: no dollar sign).

You likely picked up the dollar sign by copying from an example that featured a [Bourne shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) style prompt. The dollar sign simply indicates the end of the shell prompt and the beginning of your command, much like the `>` in your PowerShell prompt. You don't need to (and should not) type the `$` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the **$** sign

**From :**

```
$python file.py
```

**To :**

```
python file.py
```

If you are using python 3.x, you can do this also:

```
python3 file.py
```

After that you can run script file.py in terminal using python command

Answer (score -1):

Try using `python3 HW.py`or `python HW.py` rather than `$python HW.py`

Also, your code might throw an error as this might try adding a string into an int which will cause a Type error. Try running the following code, it should work perfectly if u are in the right directory in the terminal. Make sure u specify the int before input so the compiler knows that it's expecting an int from the user.

```
x = int(input("x: "))
y = x + 1
print(y)
```